# Pagination in PHP using For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

```
echo "<ul class ='pagination'>";
                for ($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
                { 

                    ?><li><a href = "pbycategories.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>"><?php echo $b; ?></a></li><?php 


                }


                echo "</ul>";

    ul.pagination {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
color: black;
float: left;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: background-color .3s;
border: 1px solid #ddd;

}

 .pagination li:first-child a {
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.pagination li:last-child a {
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

I need help in for loops .. my pagination looks like this

1      -----         2         -----     3     -----           4

5       -------          6      -----             7      -----          8

Comment: Seems a logical order for pages...  What is the question? Most of your code seems to be CSS, by the way. If your question is not about that please strip it away and keep only the parts that are relevant to your question.

Comment: Also, for the sake of your sanity, change those variables names to what they actually are. You won't remember in 6 months what those mean at all.